# how to draw a chessboard and place pawn on it in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

i a new to Netlogo. I have to design a chess board in Netlogo with pawns on it. but i really don't know how to do it. please help needed.I have drawn a little bit but it's not acceptable i want fully like as it does in real. thanks

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Post the code you have, and indicate what exactly is "not acceptable" about it.

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/community/Chess

Answer (score 3):

NetLogo makes that kind of thing relatively easy. The most straightforward approach is probably to use patches as board squares. Here is some code to get you started:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ; create-board:
  resize-world 0 7 0 7
  set-patch-size 80
  let square-colors (list (brown - 2) (brown + 2))
  (foreach sort patches range count patches [ [p i] ->
    ask p [ set pcolor item ((i + (pycor mod 2)) mod 2) square-colors ]
  ])
  ; create pieces (just pawns in this example):
  ask patches with [ pycor = 1 or pycor = 6] [
    sprout 1 [ set shape "pawn" ]
  ]
  ; set pieces color to white or black depending on their location:
  ask turtles [
    set color ifelse-value (pycor < 4) [ white ] [ black ]
  ]
end
```

This assumes that you have defined a `"pawn"` turtle shape. You'll have to make it using the Turtle Shapes Editor, and do the same for `"king"`, `"queen"`, `"bishop"`, `"knight"` and `"rook"`.

You'll have to figure out the rest by yourself. Ask questions here if you're stuck, but try to keep them precise and show us code for what you tried...